# Google Map API for generating map

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to Google map api. Even though, I never used it before. I've a simple sort of task. A user will add the Adress of his location on the website. Now, using any webservice or api, I want to get the appropriate map.

Like, I came and added my address, now, by any process or service, It will generate a google map and show me on website. How can I do this ? Please help me out!

I want to do this in php, or javascript something.

Comment: I'm nil over it. Just opened two tabs on Google API documentation. Don't know anything about it. Don't know, from where to start.

Comment: Then keep Googling for examples... you can't ask a question like this here.

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about is using the geocoding api,  here is a really good sample to get you started: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Comment: Thanks alot man! I was looking the same. I think this is the best hobby to dislike the questions rather then going on to appreciate. I even didn't acknowledged that what we call to this process. Thanks man!